# Can I publish my own books for use with D&D 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, publishing, intellectual-property

I've had artistic skills since I was a kid and I love D&D, and I want to create some books. I would be trying to fund them with KickStarter — 100 new monsters, 100 NPCs, 100 map tiles, and stuff like that. I would be doing all the art.

Is this something I can do? Is copyright a problem, and if so is there any way to avoid those problems?

Comment: related: [Is there a OGL or GSL license for D&D 5e?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45024)

Answer (score 11):

[**Angry GM** (theangrygm.com) wrote a comprehensive article on the subject here.](http://theangrygm.com/save-vs-lawsuit-how-to-publish-dd-content/) You'll learn a lot about *Open Game License* (OGL), *System Reference Document* (SRD) and other copyright considerations there. However, be warned that his writing, while full of good advice and wisdom, is liberally sprinkled with rude and vulgar language (I'm borrowing nitsua60's words here).

Basically, you have to choose between two models:

1. Limit yourself to the content given in the [SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) (with all its
   limitations). You're free to create completely new material, but you
   can't reuse or reproduce anything defined as "Product Identity" per
   the terms of the Open Gaming License.
2. Sell your work through the [Dungeon Masters Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/). Be aware,
   though, that if you choose this latter model, you won't be allowed
   to distribute it (even for free) anywhere else, and that includes
   any copy you would want to give as rewards to your contributors.

Comment: Indeed, as much as I enjoy his site, his inability to use 50 words, but instead 500, is off putting, even with profanity allowed for.

Comment: Well... i already read ALL in the link you shared from AngryGM, and its freaking confusing, i think im exactly in the same position i was when i posted this question =( its too much information LOL i really wanted to do some things for DnD 5th edition and try to fund it but im not sure =( Thank you

Comment: @LupaShiva Unfortunately, successful professional publishing (i.e., that results in making money instead of losing money) is an activity that requires either knowing a lot of  information on how to do it, or investing time and energy into learning that information.

Comment: @LupaShiva One thing I'm sure of is you have to understand perfectly the ins and outs of this business. AngryGM might not be the most concise writer, but the legal texts are not going to be easier to navigate.

Comment: While Angry can be a bit ranty and long-winded, when he gets to the meat of what he's talking about he makes it as clear as he can. This topic is simply very difficult to navigate in general. I enjoy Angry's work.

Comment: Perhaps worth clarifying on your last point whether you can give books away for free to Kickstarter backers through DM’s Guild? I think the answer is yes (other RPGs do it all the time via sister site DriveThruRPG), but I could interpret your comment either way.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie: I think the terms of DMsGuild and DriveThruRPG are quite different, despite both being part of OneBookShelf, due to DMsGuild being officially partnered with WotC. I've seen Kickstarters and the like do that with DTRPG, but not DMsGuild.

Comment: Since games cannot be copyrighted there should also be the 3rd option to not use the SRD and create something where you make it clear that although it is  "compatible with D&D" it is not from the same brand, see https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78118/45342. 

(You cannot copy exact texts as those are under copyright, a rephrasing however is not. For things that can be said only one way, which might create difficulty copyright generally also doesn't apply.)