# I want to start publishing my D&D 5e campaigns, but I dont know how

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I've made quite a few campaigns that my party has enjoyed quite a bit. I was thinking that since I am too young to have a job I could publish some of my campaigns. I have them all written in Google Docs but I dont know where and how to publish them.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Can I publish my own books for use with D&D 5th edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107856/41726)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this appears to be more about a question of publishing them as novels and not as D&D adventures. I could be wrong though

Comment: To clarify Glenn Driver's question, are these playable campaigns you've created or stories of campaigns (novels)?

Comment: They are playable campaigns

Answer (score 2):

### I recommend using the [DM's Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/) to publish your campaign.

I would also suggest reading this *[Getting Started](https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024677993-Getting-Started-on-Dungeon-Masters-Guild)* guide first, then head over to the *[FAQ](https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/categories/202531048-DMs-Guild-General-Information)*.

I know a few people who have had a good experience with selling/giving away their projects through the site.

There are some important notes about publishing it via the DM's Guild however.

- The first thing you need to know is that if you publish it through the DM's Guild, you can **never** publish that same adventure through *any other outlet*. Odds are that this won't affect you much, as you already have the adventure put together, and aren't likely to start up a Kickstarter to get funding or anything, but it also means you can't ever sell it through another publisher at any future point.
- The other important thing you need to know is that if you charge for it (including the "pay what you want" option), you only keep 50% of the profits. This may or may not be relevant, depending on if you even care about making money off of it. There's also a delay from when you can claim the money from any sale, which I think is around a month, but again, may not really even affect you if you don't plan on charging for it.

This may sound like a bunch of Doom and Gloom about the DM's Guild, but considering those are the only real downsides, and you get the benefit of being able to have your adventure be easily and widely available for a lot less effort on your part, it's a fairly nice deal.